# VueJS - How can i reload a datatable?

Tags: vue.js

I created a Vue component that loads some data fetched from my backend on a Vuetify datatable.
This table has a Delete button for each row, and when the button is hit a post request that deletes that row from my db is triggered. I'm trying to make the table reload with the new data once the button is hit, but my code doesn't work.

Here is what i tried:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="balances"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-btn @click="sendRequest(item)">
        Delete
      </v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>


<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {
 
  data() {
    return {

      search: '',

      headers: [
        { text: 'Asset', value: 'asset' },
        { text: 'Amount', value: 'amount' },
        { text: 'Delete', value: 'action' }
      ],

        balances: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      fetch('BACKEND-URL')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          this.balances = data;
        })
    },

    sendRequest(rowData) {
      console.log(rowData)

      axios.post('BACKEND-URL', 
        { 
          order_id: rowData['orderid'] 
        }, 
      );

      this.fetchData()

    }
  }
}

</script>
```

In this case, when the button is hit i call `fetchData()` again, i expected it to show the new data on the table but it does nothing. How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for promise to resolve before you can fetch data again

```js
async sendRequest(rowData) {
      console.log(rowData)

      await axios.post('BACKEND-URL', 
        { 
          order_id: rowData['orderid'] 
        }, 
      );
      this.fetchData()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Nilesh Patel is correct, you need to wait for this promise to be resolved before fetching your data again.
If you don't want to use async/await, you can continue with the same pattern you were using in your fetchData() method.

Just as you waited for the data to be fetched to continue in the `.then()` in your `fetchData` method, you will need to run whatever you want in a `.then()` in your `sendRequest` method.

something like this:

```js
    sendRequest(rowData) {
      console.log(rowData)

      axios.post('BACKEND-URL', 
        { 
          order_id: rowData['orderid'] 
        }, 
      ).then(_=>{this.fetchData()}).


    }
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is another good solution. I think i'll try to use ayìsync/await as it requires literally two more words to my code, but i'm going to try this solution too because it sounds very interesting

Answer (score 2):

use event bus for communicate events through components. declare event bus on your main js.

```
export const eventBus = new Vue();
```

then import it to your component and use $emit and $on.

```
import {eventBus} from '@/main.js';

created() {
  eventBus.$on('deleteEvent', () => {
     this.fetchData();
  });
}
```

in your delete method after call api use `eventBus.$emit('deleteEvent')`to call that event.

eg:

```
apiCall().then(() => {
  eventBus.$emit('deleteEvent');
}).catch();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is another very good solution!